# blender imported sphere with mesh collider not collided

Tags: unity

here is the scene

[image]

i imported a sphere (the blue sphere) from blender (with a hole at back), i added a mesh collider on it but it has no effect, and there is an error message
Cooking::cookConvexMesh: user-provided hull must have less than 256 vertices!.

any ideas?

(update the collider work fine after i retry and retry, but the error message still stay)

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you that the (convex) Mesh collider you want to use has way too much vertices. I can think of two solutions:

1. Just use a sphere collider...
2. Create a low-poly sphere (with no more than 256 verts) mesh in blender, and use it just for collision.

Comment: @hkguile did this answer help you? If you think it needs something more, you can write a comment to it :). Otherwise, if you consider it a good answer, can you accept it (will also give you 2 rep)?